# writing to file using scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to a file using the scrapy pipelines.py, `item` is being parsed correctly and it shows in terminal when I run.
this is my pipleines.py

```
import datetime,csv

class AmazonfullPipeline(object):
    keys = ["Product_Name","Price","Amazon_Stock","rating","ASIN","Rank1","Rank1_category","Rank2","Rank2_category",
    "UPC","Item_Model_Number"]

    def __init__(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_date = now.strftime("%d%b")
        file_name = "TestFile"
        infile = open("{}_{}.csv".format(current_date,file_name),"w").close()
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(infile, self.keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.dict_writer.writerow(item)
```

Error Message:

```
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(infile, self.keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/csv.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.writer = writer(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method
```

Comment: Check line before `infile = open("{}_{}.csv".format(current_date,file_name),"w").close()` - you open file and then close it.

Comment: @vezunchik https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197518/writing-to-a-csv-file-in-a-customized-way-using-scrapy

Comment: Sorry? My offer was to remove `close()` from line above. Did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You close file descriptor before usage;
2. You did not set class variable. Use `self.dict_writer`, not `dict_writer` in `__init__`.

Check code:

```
import datetime,csv

class AmazonfullPipeline(object):
    keys = ["Product_Name","Price","Amazon_Stock","rating","ASIN","Rank1","Rank1_category","Rank2","Rank2_category",
    "UPC","Item_Model_Number"]

    def __init__(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_date = now.strftime("%d%b")
        file_name = "TestFile"
        infile = open("{}_{}.csv".format(current_date,file_name),"w")  # <- remove close() here
        self.dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(infile, self.keys)  # <- add self. here
        self.dict_writer.writeheader()  # <- add self. here

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.dict_writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: It works, but how can I close the file when spider is finished?

Comment: Use `def close_spider(self, spider):` in pipeline for this.

Comment: I just add `self.infile.close()` in def close_spider(self, spider):    right?

Comment: Yes :) Just don't forget to make also `self.infile` in `__init__` to be able to close it.